# заблокировал сайт провайдер. Как обойти?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, веб-сайт, блок

Всем привет. Есть сайт например сайт.kz, он публичный для общего числа посетителей. Перестал открываться, когда включаю vpn сайт открывает. Подскажите, как возможно настроить редирект что бы сайт сразу перекидывался на новый домен, зеркало. Другие пользователи не будут использовать vpn, т.к. незнают что сайт заблочен. Он просто не открывается. Сайт открывается везде кроме одной страны.

Answer (score 1):

Если домен забанил РКН, сам по себе провайдер никого не банит, то

1. написать провайдеру и узнать в чём причина, если без суда не получится решить то идти в суд, если вы считаете что блокировка не законна
2. если заблочили Ip на которых в т.ч. был ваш сайт, то смените хостера

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете поднять свою копию сайта, например, на nodejs. Понадобится самый дешевый VDS.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);

function onRequest(client_req, client_res) {
  console.log('serve: ' + client_req.url);

  var options = {
    hostname: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: client_req.url,
    method: client_req.method,
    headers: client_req.headers
  };

  var proxy = http.request(options, function (res) {
    client_res.writeHead(res.statusCode, res.headers)
    res.pipe(client_res, {
      end: true
    });
  });

  client_req.pipe(proxy, {
    end: true
  });
}
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20354642/14255891)

Либо можно воспользоваться [TorBrowser](https://www.torproject.org/download/), [riseup](https://riseup.net/ru/vpn) или [calyx](https://calyx.net/).